# How do I simplify these Prisma queries into a single one?

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, query-optimization, prisma

I need to `udpate` a `User`'s last `Post` by date without knowing the `id` beforehand, I can do it with two queries like so:

```
ctx.prisma.post.update({
  where: {
    id: await ctx.prisma.post
      .findFirst({
        where: { userId: "c2e4c855-768c-48ab-b9c1-155ce1090cd6" },
        orderBy: { date: "desc" },
      })
      .then(post => post.id),
  },
  data: {
    updated: true
  },
})
```

I've been trying to get this to work as one query but I haven't been successful, and this is the best I got as a SQL clause:

```sql
UPDATE Post
SET updated = true
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT id
        FROM Post
        WHERE user_id = "c2e4c855-768c-48ab-b9c1-155ce1090cd6"
            AND date = (SELECT MAX(date) from Post)) as x);
```

Even though this is a single clause it also does two trips to the db. If there's a better way to do it in SQL I'd be interested for learning purposes but I wouldn't want to send the `raw` query with Prisma and lose all the type safety.

Is what I'm looking for possible or should I leave it as is with the two queries?

Comment: I am not aware of any solutions through which you can achieve this in a single query. It might be possible through a stored procedure and database triggers but that would mean that you have to move some of your logic to database which might not be desirable in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to update the most recent `Post` for a given `user_id`:

```
UPDATE Post
SET updated = true
WHERE user_id = 'c2e4c855-768c-48ab-b9c1-155ce1090cd6'
ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I am not sure how you would write this with prisma but this is the SQL query.

Comment: This is so much cleaner, thank you for teaching me! It doesn't look like I can do this on Prisma since I'm not able to use `orderBy` nor `take` in `update` queries, nevertheless thanks for showing me the proper way to do it in SQL :)